# How can I save the offset of ScyllaDB CDC after consumption?

Tags: java, scylla

I have read [the doc](https://docs.scylladb.com/using-scylla/cdc/) of Scylla CDC and [the Java Demo](https://github.com/scylladb/scylla-cdc-java/blob/master/scylla-cdc-printer/src/main/java/com/scylladb/cdc/printer/Main.java). After unremitting efforts in local code debugging but did not find how to save the CDC consumption offset. When my service is restarted, I will consume from the starting point, which makes me very confused.

This is my local Java Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        RawChangeConsumerProvider changeConsumerProvider = threadId -> {
            RawChangeConsumer changeConsumer = change -> {
                if (change.getOperationType().equals(RawChange.OperationType.ROW_INSERT)) {
                    ChangeId changeId = change.getId();
                    StreamId streamId = changeId.getStreamId();
                    ChangeTime changeTime = changeId.getChangeTime();
                    System.out.println("-------- change ------------ ttl is " + change.getTTL() + ", changeId is " + changeId + ", streamId  is " + streamId + ",changeTime is " + changeTime);
                }

                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
            };
            return changeConsumer;
        };

        try (CDCConsumer consumer = CDCConsumer.builder()
                .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1", 9042)
                .withCredentials("cassandra", "cassandra")
                .addTable(new TableName("cds", "outbox_event"))
                .withConsumerProvider(changeConsumerProvider)
                .withWorkersCount(1)
                .withSleepBeforeFirstGenerationMs(500)
                //.withQueryTimeWindowSizeMs(5000)
                .withConfidenceWindowSizeMs(500)
                .build()) {

            consumer.start();
            CountDownLatch terminationLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            Signal.handle(new Signal("INT"), signal -> terminationLatch.countDown());
            terminationLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.err.println("Exception occurred while running the Printer: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```